# Python, forward and modify an outlook email while keeping formating

Tags: python, automation, outlook

New on the platform, I would like to forward an email to several address. I do not find a way to do it while keeping the format and adding some content. Actually in the email I have text (bold, normal, colored) but also picture. 
I tried it with two ways : 
- save the mail in a folder (.msg) and parse it, but format is only text
- forward it directly from inbox, format is good but if I modify it same problem as the first way

Last problem,  I can't find a way to delete the forward header

```
def Emailer(text, subject, recipient):

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HTMLBody = text
    Path_Att = "D:/***/Test123.pdf"
    mail.Attachments.Add(Source=Path_Att)
    mail.Display(True)



import extract_msg

#f = r'D:\***\test13.msg' 
msg = extract_msg.Message(f)
msg_sender = msg.sender
msg_date = msg.date
msg_subj = msg.subject
msg_message = msg.body

Text_email = msg_message
Emailer(Text_email,'Our Research','xxx@xxx.com')
```

---

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders('Hugues')
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
NewMsg = message.Forward()
TestSub = NewMsg.Subject
print(type(NewMsg.Body))
NewMsg.Body = 'Hello' + NewMsg.Body
NewMsg.Subject = TestSub.replace('FW: ','')
NewMsg.To = "xxxx@xxx.com"
NewMsg.Display(True)
```

Tks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To preserve any message body formatting you need to deal with the `HTMLBody` or the Word object model where the body is represented by the `Document` class. In the code listed above you deal with a plain text string:

```
NewMsg.Body = 'Hello' + NewMsg.Body
```

And even when you set the `HTMLBody` property:

```
mail.HTMLBody = text
```

You should add any text inside the  and  elements to preserve the existing formatting and keep the HTML document well-formed.